# Is it possible to add annotations to super class variables via getters/setters (and should I)?

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, spring-data

I'm trying to consume a rest api in an app. I have 3 project modules:

1. Spring boot REST backend server
2. Application (java lib that will be used on android and iOS via robovm)
3. Models lib

I would like to use Spring data annotations to set @Id fields and @Document classes for my models, without having to include spring data in my models library (because I don't want them in my final application).

My idea was to extend the models from the models lib and to add annotations on these extended classes.

for instance:

Person in models library (lets assume this class cannot be modified):

```
public class Person
{
    String id;
    String name;
    public String getId(){return id;}
    public String getName(){return name;}
    public void setId(String id){this.id=id;}
    public void setName(String name){this.name=name;}

    Identity identity;
    public Identity getIdentity(){return identity;}
    public void setIdentity(Identity identity){this.identity=identity;}

    public static class Identity
    {
        String id;
        String name;
        public String getId(){return id;}
        public String getName(){return name;}
        public void setId(String id){this.id=id;}
        public void setName(String name){this.name=name;}
    }
}
```

MongoPerson in Spring Boot backend server (Anything can be changed here):

```
@Document
public class MongoPerson
{
    @Id
    @Override
    public String getId(){return super.getId();}

    @Indexed
    @Override
    public String getName(){return super.getName();}
}
```

Is this correct? Should I also override the setters? Or is this a bad way to go and are there better solutions for this?

Edit:
It gets more interesting (or complicated) with nested objects. How would one go about adding for instance an @Indexed to the nested id of Identity without breaking the nested object?

Comment: I would call `return super.getId();` rather than break encapsulation.

Comment: You are right, I mocked this example up and did not do it properly. I changed it in the question, thanks!